# Testing business logic in a frament in android using junit

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit

I want to write unit test cases for my android app, but my business logic is within a fragment.
From what I read its better to separate the business logic from the android component to do unit tests.

This is the function which I need to write a unit test for:

```
 private fun loadingProject(projectDetails: ProjectDetails, isOldValueNull:Boolean, isForceLoad: Boolean) {
        if (projectDetails.Project == null)
            return
        projectDetails.Project!!.isGateway = !App.instance!!.isOnlineApp

        if(Version(projectDetails.Project?.Version).isHigherThan("5")){
            val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath+"/"+App.instance!!.getString(R.string.app_name)+"/sList.json"
            val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(FileReader(path))
            val js  = Gson().fromJson(bufferedReader, Sensor::class.java)
            App.instance!!.info = js.Sensors
        }

        Project.saveProject(projectDetails.Project!!, isOldValueNull,  isForceLoad)
        if (projectDetails.Project!!.GatewayDeviceId == null) {
            showAlert()
        }
        if (projectDetails.SerialNos != null) {
            dType.remove(BeamItemTypes.SerialNos.name, App.instance!!.currentServerMode)
            projectDetails.SerialNos?.mapIndexed { index, it ->
                it.index = index
                it.Type = BeamItemTypes.SerialNos.name
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see this is a private function and this is within a fragment. What is the best approach to test this kind of a function?

Comment: You may check [this Architecture Guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide) for android and especially the [test section](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#test-components),